# Header response date is 1 hour behind

Tags: php

After the clocks changing at the weekend I am having issue with a SOAP call:

WssSoapFaultException: Failure in Timestamp validation. The creation time is ahead of the current time

Doing some digging I have found that header request date is 1 hour slow. I have check the php.ini file and the timezone is set as follows:

```
date.timezone = Europe/London
```

I believe that this date is when message was originated so why is in 1 hour behind? Is there any config I am missing?

I have checked thetime on the Apache server and anyother server used and they are all correct.

Comment: If the system clock is correct (is it?) I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: @Álvaro González Time on my PC and servers are OK, the code was working until the clocks went forward at the weekend, made me think config was wrong somewhere.

Comment: Likely due to daylight saving time (DST).

Comment: Are you actually in the London timezone? ;)

Comment: @giorgio Yes, in London timeZone :)